# Correct naming convention for a Entity that holds data from Window

Tags: naming-conventions, entity, java

I am working in a Project in which I have a window, lets say: NameOfWindow.java.

This window has some fields that the user will input data into, like checkboxes, textfields, among others.

Then there will be a not persistent entity that will be having the same fields and the Window is directly mapped with. (Architect Design Requirement).

How can I name this Entity so it will reflect its use accordingly?

I was thiking like in JSF, when they have the BackingBeans, so for example:

- NameOfWindowBackingBean.java
- NameOfWindowBean.java

Or Perhaps:

- OtherNameWindowData.java
- NameOfWindowEntity.java
- NameOfWindowHolder.java
- NameOfWindowDataHolder.java

And the list goes on, so any recommendation would be really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would probably go with Data. As I use Bean for db operating classes. 
You shouldn't worry much about this tiny details. In the end what really matters is if the naming you use in consistent along the whole project. This way if you are consistent you could in a doc 'intro' state your convention. Xxxx are 'general' classes XxxxData is a class used by class Xxxx which stores its data, something along this lines.

Plus it is always so easy to change the codein IDEs that it shouldn't bother your mind much.

Answer (score 2):

I like NameWindowData and NameWindowModel. Because it plays the role of model in MVC pattern while your NameOfWindow is actually the view.